# How to update app on GooglePlay

Tags: android

I have an app that contains built-in strings on GooglePlay. I have added new strings to the app, and I would like to know how do you update the app? Just upload the new apk under the same new?

Comment: Yes, under the same name. Have you looked at the Google Play website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new apk must have the same package name and must be signed with the same keystore file as the previous one. Thats it.

**EDIT:** oh, yes, also increment the versionCode in your manifest

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need to [increase the version](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) of your app.
Best is to check evertyhing in the [publishing your app tutorial](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

The developer console allows you to upload a new apk file for your current application.
1. Log in and select your application
2. Along the top of the page, you will see 2 tabs, Product Detail and Apk Files.  Select Apk Files
3.  There is a button that says "Upload Apk"

Answer (score 0):

you have to increment the android:versionCode in your manifest otherwise Google reject your new apk